# Getting this error Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.Onclick?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to call a js function from a html button though onclick attribute . Where i am passing two strings as parameter . I echoed two php variables though inside the argument part which seems logically correct and the function is also accepting those arguments but nothing is happening . It is giving me function is not defined with button onclick error . Below is the code :

The Script Function

```
<script>
  function displayCommentSection(var cs, var cb) {
    //  alert("in");
    // alert(cs+" "+cb);
    if (document.getElementById(cs).style.display == 'block') {
      document.getElementById(cs).style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById(cb).innerHTML = 'comment';
    } else {

      document.getElementById(cs).style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById(cb).innerHTML = 'cancel';
    }
  }

</script>


<button class="btn btn-dark" id="commentBtn<?php echo $i;?>" onclick="displayCommentSection('commentSection<?php echo $i;?>','commentBtn<?php echo $i;?>')">Comment</button>
```

Comment: Invalid JS, remove the `var` from `function displayCommentSection(var cs,
  var cb) {` - Press F12 and read the error messages in the console. Also this is not a PHP issue at all. If you have JS issues, please click the `edit`, then the `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] with relevant HTML, CSS and JS ONLY

Comment: Voting to close as typo-type question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to remove the "var" from the function definition

```
function displayCommentSection(cs,cb){     
  if(document.getElementById(cs).style.display=='block') {
           document.getElementById(cs).style.display='none';
           document.getElementById(cb).innerHTML='comment';                                                                  
        }
        else 
        {

            document.getElementById(cs).style.display='block';
            document.getElementById(cb).innerHTML='cancel';
        }
  }
```

Comment: thanks a lot . It worked . New in  js not quite familiar with the syntax yet . Thanks a lot tho